# core plot ios axis pan & zoom issue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, plot, core-plot, axis

I have problem with proper pan & zoom in my core plot graph. I created custom look for my graph and problem is with axis that are visible on outside of the graph area.

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/detail?r=f862ff3c2a3e
http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/detail?name=f862ff3c2a3e&r=b4e19c6ea51e6e1ed77072f38d6eaf05338c279f

I found on core plot site that the issue has been fixed but I had compile the latest version of Core Plot and problem is still occurs.

Pircture describe what is look like:
[image: Core Plot pan & zoom axis problem]

Any idea what maybe I have been missing?

Comment: The best solution for me is set 

    x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
    y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];

With that lines x & y axis will stay in place. (In ealier versions of Core Plot this was settable by isFloatingAxis property)